# Selecting 20 Cars from 4 Different Models

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Question: Twenty cars to be bought by a company must be selected from up to four specific models. In how many ways can the purchase be made if at most 3 different models must be purchased?

I understand one way of doing this problem:

No. of ways = Total number of ways - Number of ways when all 4 different models are purchased.

The total number of ways is given by the number of solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 20$ where $x_i \geq 0$.

The number of ways to make a purchase when all 4 different models are used is the number of solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 20$ where $x_i \geq 1$

Therefore, we get the number of ways = $C(23,3) - C(19,3)$

I don't understand why my alternative method is wrong:

1. Choose the model to be excluded: 4 ways
2. We now just need to find the number of solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 20$ where $x_i \geq 0$, Since one of the $x_i$ are 0.

Hence, the number of ways to make the purchase is $4C(22,2)$. This does not give the same answer. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The other way is a few more terms

1st Approach = ${23\choose3}-{19\choose3} = 802$

Your Approach should be =  ${4\choose3}.{22\choose2}-{4\choose2}.{21\choose1}+ {4\choose1}.{20\choose0}= 802$

Using the principle of Inclusion and Exclusion, the first term computes the number of ways you select those 20 cars with 3 model types, the second terms similarly computes the number of ways you select 20 from 2 model types and the third with 1 model type. Case 2 has to be subtracted as it has number of ways that is already included in Case 1 and finally add back Case 3 which is already included in Case 2.

To add mathematical terms in the OP's language:

Term one refers to $4*(x_1+x_2+x_3 = 20), x_i \ge 0$ with $x_4$ excluded

Term two refers to $6*(x_1+x_2 = 20), x_i \ge 0$, with $x_3$ and $x_4$ excluded

Term three refers to $ 4*(x_1 = 20) , x_1\ge 1$ with $x_2, x_3$ and $x_4$ excluded

All of them are evaluated with the formula ${(20+k-1)\choose(k-1)}, k = 1,2,3$

Comment: Including one model does not include two models twice.  It would be better to exclude one model, subtract the number of cases in which two models are excluded, and then add the number of cases in which three models are excluded.  In short, you obtained the right answer for the wrong reasons.

Comment: My verbiage is wrong.  I have done exactly what you mean. When I said includes it means cases of 1 model, 2 models and 3 models.

Comment: Again, including one model does not include two models.  You cannot apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle that way.

Comment: Is the wording correct now

Comment: No.  Including three models does not include two models twice.  If we exclude one model, we count those cases in which two models are excluded twice, once for each way we can designate one of the models as the excluded model.   Since we only want to count those cases in which two models are excluded once, we must subtract them from the total.  The reason we need to add those cases in which three models are excluded is that we counted them three times when we excluded one model and subtracted them three times when we excluded two models, so we have not counted them at all.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, we count those cases in which three models are excluded thrice when we exclude one model, once for each way of designating one of the three models as the excluded model.  We then subtract them three times when we exclude two of the models, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of excluding two of the three excluded models.  Therefore, adding cases in which we exclude one model and then subtracting cases in which we exclude two models does not count cases in which three models are excluded at all.  Since we want to count them once, we must add them back.

Comment: I think we are beating on the term "include".  I mean "include" to refer to the number of ways that are covered in each case.  You mean "include" to refer to the model type inclusion. I am right on my language to refer "include" to mean the number of ways in all cases.  I am sorry but I thought I was clear the second time.  Feel free to change or edit if you feel my language is not very explanatory.